# Performance Between IN Clause with Multiple Values and Less Than or Greater Than

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to understand the performance implications of using a case statement which includes an IN clause containing multiple values (query 1 below) versus a single less than logical operator (query 2 below). Does the IN clause have to perform multiple logical checks on a given field? For example, assuming a row does not meet the first query's criteria of equaling 1, does the next record have to have its first_rating_number field checked for 2, then 3, then 4 if none of those are present? Would this be slower than a first_rating_number < 5 (as it is in the second query)?

I ran an execution plan and Oracle is telling me that the cost is equivalent and that bytes are slightly higher in the second query. This does not make sense to me. Thanks to all in advance.

Edit - Additional Information: Yesterday, I was receiving different Bytes with the first query showing less. Today, both plans are showing identical Explain Plan information.

Number of Rows: 1,261,914

Query 1 Explain Plan: Cost - 22,134; Bytes - 3,785,742

Query 2 Explain Plan: Cost - 22,134; Bytes - 3,785,742

```
SELECT 
  CASE  WHEN first_rating_number = 1 THEN 'AAA' 
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (2,3,4) THEN 'AA' 
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (5,6,7) THEN 'A' 
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (8,9,10) THEN 'BBB' 
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (11,12,13) THEN 'BB'
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (14,15,16) THEN 'B'
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (17,18,19) THEN 'CCC'        
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (20) THEN 'CC'                     
         WHEN first_rating_number IN (22) THEN 'D'  END first_rating_category_test
  FROM tbl_IN_CLAUSE;
```

```
SELECT 
  CASE  WHEN first_rating_number = 1 THEN 'AAA' 
         WHEN first_rating_number <5 THEN 'AA' 
         WHEN first_rating_number <8 THEN 'A' 
         WHEN first_rating_number <11 THEN 'BBB' 
         WHEN first_rating_number <14 THEN 'BB'
         WHEN first_rating_number <17 THEN 'B'
         WHEN first_rating_number <20 THEN 'CCC'        
         WHEN first_rating_number = 20 THEN 'CC'                     
         WHEN first_rating_number = 22 THEN 'D'  END first_rating_category_test
  FROM tbl_LESS_THAN;
```

Comment: You should show what the bytes calculations are for the query.  There might be slightly different assumptions on the distribution of discrete versus continuous checks.  If so, I would expect the difference to be quite marginal.

Comment: Please provide your explain plan for both queries, and indicate how many rows are stored in the table(s).

Comment: This is not what you asked, but: if speed is important (although in such an application it is not really clear why it should be), you may be better off creating a small lookup table with the rating number and the letter ratings, index the rating number (better: make it primary key), index the rating number in `tbl_less_than` (better: make it foreign key), and use a join rather than a `case` expression.

Comment: The concern I have for the second query is, let's assume rating number is 4, it is less than 5, but it is also less than rest of the values, in that case, your query becomes sequence based as case statement will be executed in order they are written and you may get wrong output(if the second case is anything after the second position) wherein the case of the first query where you are using IN, will give you exact answer each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a test for this if you like, but logic suggests that the inequalities approach should be faster. (HOW MUCH faster you can only find out by testing.)

Why?

Because an inequality is a single test. By contrast, `x in (3, 4, 5, 6, 7)` is five tests, and all five must be tried, in order, if `x = 7` or if `x` is not in the list. The `in` condition is rewritten as `x = 3 or x = 4 or x = 5 ...` and these tests can't be run in parallel - they are checked one at a time.

Comment: These were my exact thoughts which is what led me to post the problem. I executed the queries around 10 times each and didn't notice any material difference in execution speeds. Then, I ran the Explain Plan and got a lower Bytes number for the first query which surprised me. Today, when I Explain Plan on both queries, I receive identical statistics.